# Asynchronous image download

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following code is within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I need to edit this code to the following situations;

1.) If there was a problem to download the image this block should return a `setFailedBlock` block, How can i add it to my code ?

2.) While the image is downloading the user changes the view, then i want to stop executing this code (Stop the download). I think i should write the cancel the block in the `viewdiddissapear` or `viewwilldissapear` methods. But i don't know how to write the code to cancel the download. Can someone show me how to do this ?

(note: this block is inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method so have to access it from `viewdiddissapear` or `viewwilldissapear`)

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{        
    NSData *someimageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someimageURL]];        
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [cell.imageviewofsomeimage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:someimageData ] ];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use NSURLConnection, this class has [cancel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/cancel)

[AsyncURLConnection discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037545/nsurlconnection-and-grand-central-dispatch)

Comment: Isn't there a solution to do it with blocks it self. as in to set a `setFailedBlock ` ?

Comment: @Illep: Blocks are not a magic bullet.  Use them where appropriate.  At first sight this does not look like an appropriate place because the block friendly methods cannot be canceled.

Comment: @JeremyP Ok, then what is the correct way of doing it ? the suitable workaround

Comment: @Illep: if you want to be able to cancel a download, it looks like you need to instantiate an `NSURLConnection`, set a delegate and implement the delegate methods. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-170129

Comment: I am also using `ASIRequest` So is there a way to do it using  `ASIRequest`  ?