# How Do I Run an Entire Object (DAO.h and .m) in Separate Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Are there ways to run entire objects in a separate thread using GCD? Or put another way, how do I run DAO.m in it's own thread?  There are some long running operations that are intimately bound to the object they run in. Details: we have a sqlite3 database with several long running operations that currently prevent the application from running on the device (iPad 2) but they work in the simulator- but block the main thread. Optimizing the SQL will not improve the performance enough. We're downloading files from the net, processing the files and putting the results in the database. We already download asynchronously.

Comment: Do you mean to run every instance method of an object on a specific thread, regardless of which thread the method was called from?

Comment: No, I want to run every instance method on a background thread and it doesn't matter to me where a method is called. Run it somewhere other than the main thread so I don't block the UI. Is that clear? I'm not sure I'm asking clearly. What I really want to do is avoid rewriting a complex object to use blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. All thanks to a co-worker and [NSURLConnection and grand central dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037545/nsurlconnection-and-grand-central-dispatch) .

I didn't really need the URL connection to be in the block but I need to deal with the response asynchronously.

```
[AsyncURLConnection request:pathToProducts  url:getProductsURL completeBlock:^(NSData *data) {

    /* success! */

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dAO = [DAO getInstance]; 
    /* do processing here */

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            /* update UI on Main Thread */

        });
    });

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Well that sucked!");
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got your intention right, but here's an idea - you may subclass `NSProxy` to wrap your DAO instance and forward any invocation to its own serial queue. Something like this (beware, not tested/compiled):

```
@interface DAOProxy : NSProxy

- (DAO *)initWithDAO:(DAO *)dao;

@end



@implementation DAOProxy {
    dispatch_queue_t _daoQueue;
    DAO *dao;
}

- (DAO *)initWithDAO:(DAO *)dao {
    // no call to [super init] - we are subclassing NSProxy
    _dao = dao;
    _daoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyDaoQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    return (DAO *)self;
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return [_dao respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return [_dao methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    dispatch_async(_daoQueue, ^{
        [anInvocation setTarget:_dao];
        [anInvocation invoke];
    });
}

@end
```

And usage:

```
DAO *realDao = ...;
DAO *proxiedDao = [[DAOProxy alloc] initWithDAO:realDao];
// use proxiedDao as you would use the real one from there
```

Some additional trickery will be needed if you want to get return results of DAO methods, like passing callback blocks to execute them in a caller thread when the result is ready... Well, that's a general problem you get with asynchronicity.

Comment: That's in interesting idea. I wish I had time to try that out.