# How to show loading view controller in my webservices

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

I want to show a loading view controller or activity indicator view when I call my loginUserintoserver method but while debugging I found the view becomes inactive at this line.

```
 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

For sometime till I get the response. I have tried showing activity indicators but did not succeed. Please any guidelines to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

```
-(void) loginUserintoserver
```

{

```
NSString *str_validateURL = @"callogin";
```

//    em,password,devicereg,devicetype,flag = ("e" or "m")

```
NSString *str_completeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", str_global_domain, str_validateURL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str_completeURL];


NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

str_global_UserPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",signupCountryCodeTextField.text,signupMobileTextField.text];

NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"em=%@&password=%@&devicereg=%@&devicetype=%@&flag=%@", loginEmailTextField.text, loginPasswordTextField.text, str_global_DeviceRegID, @"1", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", emailphoneFlag]];

NSLog(@"==============%@",postData);
NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

[theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[theRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

// here the view becomes inactive and takes time to get response from server

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"response data is %@", responseData);

if (responseData == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"No data from server");

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"No data downloaded from server!"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"response data is %@", responseData);
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"returnString....%@",returnString);

    NSDictionary *response_dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSString *msg;
    msg = [response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"];
    NSDictionary *loginDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    loginDict=[response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"];
    NSLog(@"msg is  : %@ ",[response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"]);

    if ([[[response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"] objectForKey:@"ErrorCode"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        // success
        NSLog(@"Successfull Login!!!!!");

        NSString *UserId=[loginDict objectForKey:@"userid"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UserId  forKey:@"LoginId"];

        [self initRevealViewController];


    } else if ([[[response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"] objectForKey:@"ErrorCode"] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        NSLog(@"Invalid Password!");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message: @"ReEnter Password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];


    }else if ([[[response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"] objectForKey:@"ErrorCode"] isEqualToString:@"3"]){
        NSLog(@"Invalid input parameters!");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message: @"Email address or Mobile number, Password, devicereg, devicetype, flag are Mandatory" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];


    }else if ([[[response_dic objectForKey:@"Result"] objectForKey:@"ErrorCode"] isEqualToString:@"6"]){
        NSLog(@"Invalid input parameters!");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message: @"User Registered but not activated" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You better dispatch your request in background..

Comment: You have to decide if your view controller is unusable before the data is fetched the you can show activity indicator in any manner by using MBProgresshud or by making one your self...but if your view controller is usable without fetching data then fetch data in background.

Comment: @amar : please elaborate more on dispatch request in background.

Comment: search how to make async request u can use afnetworking or can make it using nsmutableurlrequest as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answers are partial which do not point out the main issue in your code.

Synchronous request on main thread will block it, thus you cannot show any UI updates like activity indicator while the sync request is in progress. Instead make asynchronous request (or make request in background using GCD) and use `UIActivityIndicatorView` or any other open source available for this.

Follow this Q&A to learn how to make asyn request using GCD: [NSURLConnection and grand central dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037545/nsurlconnection-and-grand-central-dispatch)

You can create and add an activity indicator to the view. Present and start showing activity when request is initiated and stop the activity when request completes downloading.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You have to used this: [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Import framwork from above link and do some stuff like:

.h file:

```
   #import "MBProgressHUD.h"

   MBProgressHUD *HUD;
```

.m file do this :

```
      HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
      [self.view addSubview:HUD];

      [HUD show:YES];
      // call your webservice here

      [HUD hide:YES];
```

May be it will help.

Happy coding...:)

Comment: what's the diffrent betweent your ans and @Erhan..?

Comment: @NitinGohel i put before his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mak ,

I use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) all my project . You can use also .Really MBProgressHUD is suitable , lightweight.

Showing indicator :

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

hiding  :

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Download the project for MBProgressHUD , and copy MBProgressHUD.h & .m classes in to your project, Now by simply creating an instance of MBProgressHUD and using the available methods by MBProgressHUD you can show loading view on to your web services

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window];
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loginUserintoserver) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview:HUD];
```

Hope it will help you .