# MBProgessHUD show on method execution

Tags: ios, xcode5, mbprogresshud

I am writing app that will Sync with address book and keep itself updated to `addressbook`.

When i am calling the syncing method or when its first launch and the app is copying all `addressbook` contact to the app data file, i want to show `MBProgressHUD` to the user.

I don't understand this well, i want the `MBProgressHUD` to show up on the call of this method, and to hide when its done.

```
- (void)syncingAddressbookWithCoreDataFile
```

Can you guide me how to use it in the way that i want?

I am confused with all the `dispatch` and the queues stuff because i am quite novice in all these things.

UPDATED

How can i make the `progress` of the indicator fill in as the task gets executed, i know there is a `progress` property in HUD (i am using `MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate`), but when i increase its value while my method is executing it doesn't change.. do i need to call something like redisplay?

Comment: When you are calling the Sync method you should call [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES] and then when syncing is finished you should call [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:keyWindow animated:animated]. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139428/how-to-show-loading-view-controller-in-my-webservices/20139529#20139529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code, you have the simpliest way to do what you want. It's not blocking the UI.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView: self.view];
[self.view addSubview: hud];
hud.labelText = @"Please wait...";

[hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
    [self syncingAddressbookWithCoreDataFile];
} completionBlock:^{
    // Put here code like reload table, refresh UI (...)
}];
```

But warning, as `whileExecutingBlock` using thread you have to make all UI change on main thread.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you.
If i want to display completed indicator just after completion, do i create another HUD? or that would be a normal view?

What if i want to make loading indicator (circle filling) while syncing, is that too much advanced?

Comment: Look in demos from MBProgressHud, there are all you want https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/tree/master/Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)syncingAddressbookWithCoreDataFile { 

      [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

      //Your code goes here


      [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code where you want to **show** progress :

```
  [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

Now Add this code where you want to **hide** progress

```
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Set your view where you want to display progress in : `showHUDAddedTo && hideHUDForView`

Comment: I called `[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];` 
before just before i call my sync method and hide after it.. It doesn't work.

Comment: You've to add MBProgressHUD to your view.